# Word for large, short, wide, roundish, fat bottle

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What word would you use to describe a large, short, wide, roundish, fat bottle, the kind used for some wines: *tubby* or *chubby*?

This kind of flask called *growler* would match my request, but I'd like to learn what adjectives could describe this shape.

[image]

Comment: Old beer bottles (in Canada, don't know about the US and I don't know where you're located) are known as stubbies. Could that be what you're thinking of?

Comment: I think of growlers as "jugs" rather than "bottles" -- milk comes in half gallon or gallon *jugs*,

Comment: Australia uses 'stubbies' vs. 'long-necks' about beer bottles, too, though stubbies are usually ≈375ml, and long-necks 750ml. Then there's the infamous 'Darwin Stubby' - which is 2L or so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Darwin_stubby.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would describe it as *[squat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squat)*:

> b : marked by disproportionate shortness or thickness

Comment: ...although I must say "hearty jug" sounds just as good :)

Answer (score 2):

The technical term, which is obscure, is [urceolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urceolate).

(*EDITED BASED ON REFINED QUESTION*)

Comment: In the UK a jug has a handle and a spout or lip.

Comment: @BarrieEngland We'd call that a *pitcher*.

Comment: Fine, but how would you describe the shape? Especially if I want to remain clear this is not a typical, open-top jug/pitcher, but a flask with a cork?

Comment: @SF Oh, you are looking for a word for the shape of such a bottle. That was not entirely clear to me from your question.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, sorry for not expressing myself clearly enough (I hoped "adjective" in keywords would suffice)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that a *[chestnut flask](http://www.sha.org/bottle/liquor.htm#Chesnut%20Flasks)* closely resembles your description, "large, short, wide, roundish, 'fat' bottle".

However, *[handled liquor bottle](http://www.sha.org/bottle/liquor.htm#Handled%20liquor%20bottles)* is generically accurate for the flask or bottle with handle as shown in your picture.  Previously-mentioned *squat* is used in descriptions of [cylindrical spirits bottles](http://www.sha.org/bottle/liquor.htm#Squat%20spirits%20cylinder%20bottles) without handles also.

Some other terms for [fat, roundish bottles](http://www.sha.org/bottle/liquor.htm#Bottle%20Typing%20Organization%20and%20Structure%20block) that may be relevant include *Benedictine bottles, Pitkin flasks, Union Oval flasks, Shoo-fly & Coffin flasks, Picnic/Jo Jo flasks, Barrel flasks, Eagle flasks, Olympia & Washington style flasks, Baltimore Oval Flasks,* and *Dandy Flasks*.

Answer (score 2):

I think of growlers and similarly large vessels as *jugs* rather than *bottles* -- milk comes in half gallon or gallon *jugs*, for instance. Definitely a vessel of that shape filled with wine would be a *jug of wine* ... so an *urcolate jug* perhaps? Or a *hearty jug* (which gets the essence but not the shape).

The site that @jwpat7 cites calls them simply [squat](http://www.sha.org/bottle/liquor.htm#Squat%20spirits%20cylinder%20bottles).